# How to add tikz plot on the title page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to add this plot [image: plot](code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425596/174285)) below the title on the cover page.

[image: cover]

How can i do it?

This is the source of the document.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{authblk}
    % Title, author and date
    \title{\Huge \textbf{Title}}
    \author{\textsc{John Doe}}
    \affil{Department of Mathematics}
    \date{2020}


    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter % Turns on roman numbering
    \maketitle
 \end{document}%
```

Comment: As long as you do not show us the code that produces the current title page, it is rather hard to answer the question. Also the code you link to does not necessarily reproduce the plot you show in detail.

Comment: I added the code but i don't know how this could help considering that is just a basic template.

Comment: Well, it is important to know what you are using. The package `authblk` is not necessarily made for adding graphics at the title page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `authblk` style does not seem to be made for this. It redefines the `\maketitle` command by locally redefining the `tabular` environment to become a `center` environment. One can exploit this to place the graphics. However, due to the `authblk` hacks, `\endcenter` gets executed twice so we need to take care of this, too.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}%<- use a smaller version if you have an older installation
% Title, author and date
\title{\Huge \textbf{Title}}
\author{\textsc{John Doe}}
\affil{Department of Mathematics}
\date{2020}

\newsavebox\myplot
\sbox\myplot{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad,axis lines=left,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,domain=0:4,xmin=-0.5,
    xlabel=$n$,ylabel=$X_n$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:1,0)}},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:1,0)},rotate=-90,anchor=west}]
\addplot[smooth,red,dashed,very thick] {1+exp(-x)};
\addplot[smooth,red,dashed,very thick] {1-exp(-x)};
\addplot[only marks,mark=*,color=blue!70!black,samples=151] {1+exp(-x)*sin(10*x)};
\end{axis}
\path (current bounding box.north) + (0,1); % add some vertical space
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\oldendcenter\endcenter
\edef\mypftflag{0}%
\def\endcenter{%
\xdef\mypftflag{\the\numexpr\mypftflag+1}%
\ifnum\mypftflag>1\relax
\usebox\myplot
\fi
\oldendcenter}
\frontmatter % Turns on roman numbering

\maketitle
\endgroup

\section{pft}
\end{document}%
```

[image]